# Count total number of words in Illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am designing a poster in Adobe Illustrator (ver. 2019), and one of the suggestions I am following is keeping the total number of words around 150.

Is there a way to count all words (inside text boxes) in Illustrator?

Comment: Hi Guiherme, Welcome to Graphic Design. I'm intrigued by this suggestion from a behavioural POV. Can you please point me toward the source of this suggestion? Normally, my clients supply the wording for a poster. Normally, my clients don't appreciate being succinct. This research will help my editing efforts. You could edit the link into your question at the end.

Comment: @Stan The suggestion comes from this link: https://www.animateyour.science/post/how-to-design-an-award-winning-conference-poster The idea of a poster is to be a visual representation of the abstract, so few words should be used. But again, this is a suggestion, it may or may not make sense in different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy that text content and paste it into MS Word, or Notepad++ or a blank Google Drive document. All of these tools have a built-in word count tool.

Kind of a work around if you don't want to leave Illustrator:

- Do a Find/Replace and replace every space with a $ sign or some character you don't already have in your document.
- Hit Replace All and then the Find/Replace will tell you how many spaces were replaced. Assuming regular flowing text, your word count will be more or less equal to this number of spaces.
- Finally, don't forget to Undo! :)

Comment: I do not want to have to copy and paste everything outside Illustrator, so your suggestion is a good approach! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It works. Here's the step by step: unlock all layers, click on menu Edit > Find and Replace ..., on Find insert a whitespace and on Edit insert $, click on Find, then click on Replace All. A window will pop up saying how many words were replaced. Click Ok, then undo changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the text available in InDesign, you can simply highlight the text with the Info window (Window > Info) open and it'll tell you characters, words, lines and paragraphs.

I agree that there should be a way to have a word count in illustrator - but perhaps that's because if you have 150 words on a document, InDesign is a better option for layout and workflow?

Comment: I am not familiar with InDesign. But it seems like it isn't something too difficult to code. One just needs to "select" all text boxes, and count how the words.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of not being able to paste text from illustrator. I discovered that it works when using an online wordcounter. (for instance wordcounter.net).

Answer (score 0):

Cutting and pasting into a Word document does not work. It will just paste a text box with words that cannot be counted.
The best option is to do everything in Word or a similar program beforehand; don't add/change anything once you've imported it into Illustrator or InDesign.